# setting default values for dropdown with optiongroup using Jquery select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using Jquery Plugin [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#basics). I am creating option groups in dropdown list and using select 2 to make default selection using Jquery like this:

```
$(function () {      

    $('#<%= list.ClientID %>').select2({
        placeholder: "Select a Category",
        allowClear: true
    });

var SelectedIndustry = $('#<%= SelectedValuesHF.ClientID %>').val();  // "210,220"
```

and then this:

```
 $('#<%= list.ClientID %>').select2("val", $('#<%= SelectedValuesHF.ClientID %>').val());
```

but this is not working.

where as this is working:

```
 $('#<%= list.ClientID %>').select2("val", ["220", "227"]); // with hardcode values.
```

Please suggest me solution to this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your code sample:

```
var SelectedIndustry = $('#<%= SelectedValuesHF.ClientID %>').val();  // "210,220"
```

The variable `SelectedIndustry` will be a string and not an array, which must be passed to select2.

You probably need to transform the string into an array with something like this:

```
var SelectedIndustry = $('#<%= SelectedValuesHF.ClientID %>').val();  // "210,220"

// pass an array created by split
$('#<%= list.ClientID %>').select2("val", SelectedIndustry.split(',') );
```

Comment: This is not working as well. when i put debugger, it doesnt show values as ['201', '210'] after split. rather shows array with values at 0 and 1 indices

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: The answer of **milz** are base on the information from your question that `SelectedIndustry` is equal to "210,220". If `SelectedIndustry.split(',')` is not `["201","210"]` then *you have to verify one more time the value of `SelectedIndustry`*.

Comment: @oleg, you were right, i needed array with int elements not string elements.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: You are welcome! I'm glad that the problem is solved finally. Don't forget to vote all helpful answers or questions. It's the main criteria for the searching engine. You have right to vote 30 answers or questions **per day** (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213)), but you used the right only 20 times in more as 3.5 years. Please be not so economic and help other people to find good information on stackoverflow. I recommend you to vote up everything which bring you in correct direction of which gives you some good tips.In the way you helps other visitors.